# Database as a Service provider for a small retail business

Tags: database, cloud-computing

I'm asking this question for a friend.
My friend downloaded [Unicenta](https://unicenta.com/) to replace their previous accounting software, and wants to be able to work from home by keeping their database in the cloud.

There are several database providers out there, and I don't which one would be best for their needs.

What they would desire are:
Reliability: Something trustworthy, not likely to crash.
Availability: The Database should be online, readily available 24/7, and at high speed preferably limited only by the client computer.
Ease-of-use: My friend is not a power user, and would like the service to be easy to use (though I'm available to help with installation).
Ability to easily backup the database, multiple users able to access and update the database, and different permissions per users would be welcome.
Price: My friend is willing to pay $20 per annum.

The database only needs to be able handle the accounting software, and as such wouldn't be particularly large.

If the price range of the software that meets the above requirements does not intersect (or only the lower quality products intersect), then the price range may be increased.

Comment: What databases does Unicenta support? I glanced at their web site but not see any list of supported databases.

Comment: Besides db-as-a-service, you might consider using a VM from a provider such as Digital Ocean, using a prebuilt BSD or Linux OS on which you install your choice of database.